# Initializing arraylist without object type - JAVA

Tags: java, list, arraylist

This question is not about why we initialize a list as interface over implementation e.g.

```
List<myObject> obj = new ArrayList<myObject>();
```

The question is what is the difference between the following two and why do they (apparently) work the same way?

```
//list and arraylist both have a type
List<myObject> obj = new ArrayList<myObject>();

//arraylist does not have a type
List<myObject> obj = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: They are both the same thing. The diamond operator was introduced in java 7 as a shortcut so that you as a programmer don't have to unnecessary repeat yourself: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both pieces of code are equivalent and create `ArrayList`s with a *type* (`myObject` in your example):

```java
List<myObject> obj = new ArrayList<myObject>();
```

```java
List<myObject> obj = new ArrayList<>();
```

However the second example uses the **diamond operator** (`<>`) introduced in Java 7. It adds type inference and reduces the verbosity in the assignments.

---

See the following quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

> You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor
>   of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (`<>`) as long
>   as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context. This
>   pair of angle brackets is informally called the diamond.
>
> For example, consider the following variable declaration:
>
> ```
> Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
> ```
>
> In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the
>   constructor with an empty set of type parameters (`<>`):
>
> ```
> Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, Java assumes the type is myObject. So there is still a type.